# How to build spring integration samples with gradlew?

Tags: spring-integration, gradlew

I cloned spring integration samples from below url.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples

And I tried build with gradlew. but build failed.

```
D:\workspace_spring\spring-integration-samples>gradlew build
```

> Task :barrier:bootJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':barrier:bootJar'.
> Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [org.springframework.integration.samples.barrier2.ErrorHandlingApplication, org.springframework.integration.samples.barrier.Application]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
19 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 18 up-to-date

```
D:\workspace_spring\spring-integration-samples>gradlew -v
```

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_202 (Oracle Corporation 25.202-b08)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Why this build error is occured?
Is it related to gradle's version?

Any little clue even would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that we had upgraded Spring Boot but didn't change the respective config for Gradle.

More over we have never call `build`: only `clean check` is enough for us. But I see your point and I am fixing it right now to the proper actual Spring Boot Gradle plugin config.

See the fix here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/commit/c72d642f35414089cfe33a2b32414ec0a869f8a6

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't upvote(I havn't 15 reputation yet). But I want to say thanks!